# Reemplazar cada vocal por la siguiente en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola buenas estaba realizando un código donde tengo que reemplazar cada vocal por la siguiente.
Por ejemplo:

Entrada: vestuario.

Salida: vistaerou.

El problema esta en que me devuelve la palabra separada en letras:

Salida: v i s t a e r o u

Cada funcion esta diseñada porque no nos dejan usarlas en python.

```
subcadena = list()
def joinstr(subcadena):
    string = ""
    for x, val in enumerate(subcadena):
        if x == len(subcadena) -1:
            string+=val
        else:
            string+= val + " "
    return string

def split(vocales):
    Vectorpalabras = []
    tmp = ''
    for c in vocales:
        if c == ' ':
            if tmp != '':
                Vectorpalabras.append(tmp)
            tmp = ''
        else:
            tmp += c
    if tmp:
        Vectorpalabras.append(tmp)
    

    return Vectorpalabras

cadena = str(input("Ingrese una cadena: "))
vocales = 'a e i o u'
vocales = split(vocales)
temp = dict(zip(vocales, vocales[1:] + [vocales[0]]))
subcadena =([temp.get(ele, ele) for ele in cadena])
subcadena = joinstr(subcadena)
print("La nueva cadena es: " + str(subcadena))
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de entrada, la salida que actualmente produce y el resultado correcto esperado.

Comment: Pero si la separación la estás creando tú mismo en la función `joinstr()`! Esa función intercala un espacio entre letras. ¿por qué lo haces si no querías hacerlo?

Comment: Porque las palabras estan almacenadas en un vector y tengo que pasarla a una cadena

Answer (score 0):

Invertiste la comparación en

```
def joinstr(subcadena):
    string = ""
    for x, val in enumerate(subcadena):
        if x == len(subcadena) -1:
            string+=val
        else:
            string+= val + " "
    return string
```

Estás agregando un espacio por cada caracter, excepto el último.

**Versión correcta**

Agrega un espacio solo en la última letra:

```
def joinstr(subcadena):
    string = ""
    for x, val in enumerate(subcadena):
        if x == len(subcadena) - 1:
            string += val + " "
        else:
            string += val 
    return string
```

**Versión resumida**

No necesitas llevar la cuenta de los elementos; simplemente concatenalos todos y al final agrega el espacio que falta.

```
def joinstr(subcadena):
    string = ""
    for letra in subcadena:
        string += letra
    return string + " "
```

Comment: Si ya lo hice gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Añado una version simplificada por si alguien la necesita en el futuro. Saludos!!!

```
def siguiente_vocal(palabra):
vocales = ['a','e','i','o','u']
lista_letras = list(palabra)
for indice,letras in enumerate(lista_letras):
    if letras in vocales and letras != 'u':
        lista_letras[indice] = vocales[vocales.index(letras) + 1]
    if letras in vocales and letras == 'u':
        lista_letras[indice] = vocales[0]
palabra_nueva = ''.join(lista_letras)
print(palabra_nueva)
 
siguiente_vocal("Vestuario")
```

Comment: _Este sitio no es un repositorio de código_. Por favor, explica brevemente su funcionamiento: recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP, sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Además, ¿cómo resuelve este código el problema del OP?